# Composer package class not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to create a composer package but I'm getting a class not found error. I'm using Laravel 4 but I'm trying to create a generic PHP package.

I created the package in my vendor/ directory.

```
vendor/
    theninthnode/
        defaqto/
            src/
                Defaqto.php
    vendor/
    composer.json
```

Here is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "theninthnode/defaqto",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Billy Jones",
            "email": "billyjones26@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src"]
    }
}
```

And my class:

```
<?php

class Defaqto
{
....
}
```

When I try to call the package class from my app like so

```
$defaqto = new Defaqto();
```

I just get

```
Class 'Defaqto' not found
```

I've tried `composer dump-autoload` from within my package and also my applications root.

I also tried adding `theninthnode/defaqto` to my root composer.json file.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you include the composer's `autoload.php` in your code?

Comment: "I created the package in my vendor/ directory." --- `vendor` directory is to be handled by composer, you should never change anything there.

Comment: @zerkms I hadn't but I've added ```require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';``` to my controller but still class not found :(

Comment: @zerkms where would you keep your project until you were ready to submit it to packagist if not in ```vendor```

Comment: check any project that is on packagist https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/ - there is no any `vendor` directories in the sources

Comment: I've seen vendor directories inside a composer package before. For instance mustachephp https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php. It was autocreated with ```composer install```. I haven't touched it though..

Comment: `vendor` directory is supposed to be handled by composer. That's it. Mustache uses it for its own purposes and I don't see it as a good idea